# Jquery columns draggable tree div

Tags: jquery, tree, draggable, drag

I have a problem and I want to do that can move 3 div (more later) to move in the X axis min and max have a position relative to the container.
Initially works well but when you start moving the separators several times begins the problem, does not respect the minimum or the maximum, I wonder if someone can help me to know what could be the problem (They can check in the browser console where the values ​​are updated according to move the separators are.)  https://jsfiddle.net/66un403y/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

$(function(){
   var A = parseInt($('#A').width()),
       B = parseInt($('#B').width()),
       C = parseInt($('#C').width()),

       minw       = parseInt((A + B + C) * 10 / 100), //  min 10 percentage
       offset     = $('#container').offset(),
       containw   = $('#container').outerWidth(),
       splitter_1 = $('#container').outerWidth() / 3;
       splitter_2 = (($('#container').outerWidth() / 3) * 2);

       $("#min_width").text(minw + "px");

       splitter = function(event, ui){
            $( '#DragContent' ).unbind( 'draggable' );
            A = parseInt(ui.position.left);
            B = Math.abs(containw - A - C);
            C = containw - A - B;

            splitter_1 = ui.position.left;
            splitter_2 = splitter_2;
            console.log("A:" + A);
            console.log("B:" + B);
            console.log("C:" + C);
            console.log("splitter_1:" + splitter_1);
            console.log("splitter_2:" + splitter_2);
            console.log("offset.left:"+offset.left);
            console.log("ui.position.left:"+ ui.position.left);
            console.log("max:"+ (A + B - minw));
            console.log("min:"+ ( minw ));

            // update the new limits
            //$( '#X' ).unbind( 'draggable' );
            $( '#X' ).draggable({
              containment : [
                 offset.left + minw,
                 offset.top,
                 offset.left + C + B - minw,
                 offset.top + $('#container').height()
            ]});


           //set widths and information...
           $('#A').css({width : A}).children().text("current px: " + A);
           $('#B').css({width : B}).children().text("current px: " + B);
           $('#C').css({width : C}).children().text("current px: " + C);;
       };
       splitter2 = function(event, ui){


          C = containw - (ui.position.left);
            B = Math.abs( ui.position.left - A );//parseInt(ui.position.left) - A - C;
          A = containw - (B + C);

         splitter_1 = splitter_1;
         splitter_2 = ui.position.left;
         console.log("A:" + A);
         console.log("B:" + B);
         console.log("C:" + C);
         console.log("splitter_1:" + splitter_1);
         console.log("splitter_2:" + splitter_2);
         console.log("offset.left:"+offset.left);
         console.log("ui.position.left:"+ ui.position.left);
         console.log("limite:"+ (containw - minw));
         console.log("minimo:"+ ( A + minw ));



         // update the new limits
         //$( '#X' ).unbind( 'draggable' );
         $('#Z').draggable({
          containment : [
             offset.left + A + minw,
             offset.top,
             offset.left + containw - minw,
             offset.top + $('#container').height()
        ]});
         $('#A').css({width : A}).children().text("current px: " + A);
         $('#B').css({width : B}).children().text("current px: " + B );
         $('#C').css({width : C}).children().text("current px: " + C  );

       };

   $('#X').draggable({
      axis : 'x', 
      drag : splitter,
      containment : [
                   offset.left + minw,
                   offset.top,
                   offset.left + C + B - minw,
                   offset.top + $('#container').height()
              ]
   });

   $('#Z').draggable({
       axis : 'x',
       drag : splitter2,
       containment : [
             offset.left + A + minw,
             offset.top,
             offset.left + containw - minw,
             offset.top + $('#container').height()
        ]
   });


   //information...
   $('#width').text(A + B + C);
   $('#A div').text("current px: " + A );
   $('#B div').text("current px: " + B );
   $('#C div').text("current px: " + C );
   console.log();
});

});
```

Comment: your code is not good even on window resize. The separators go off place... :(

Comment: Yes, if you make the window bigger press Run again. But I would like someone to help me with the request of the problem I have

Comment: Fixed that problem converting all back to `%` on drag end

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for not coping with your exact code, but just to show you how I'd create

### Resizable sibling containers

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/lurawu/5/edit?html,css,js,output)***

Will handle any number of *resizable* boxes, and keep them **Responsive** thanx to the width conversion back to `%` on resize end:

```js
var minWidth = 50, // Set here the minimal resize width
    $box = $(".box"),
    $cont = $box.parent(),

    startX = 0,
    isDrag = false,

    $that, thatW = 0,
    $next, nextW = 0;

$(".resizeHandler").on('mousedown', function( e ) {

  isDrag = true;
  startX = e.pageX;

  $that = $(this).closest(".box");
  thatW = $that.width();

  $next = $that.next(".box");
  nextW = $next.width();
  
  $box.css({userSelect: isDrag?'none':'auto'});

});

$(document).on('mousemove', function( e ) {

  if(!isDrag) return;
  var x = e.pageX;

  var nextWNew = Math.max(minWidth, nextW + startX - x);
  var thatWNew = Math.max(minWidth, thatW + x - startX);
  if(thatWNew <= 50) return thatWNew = minWidth;
  if(nextWNew <= 50) return nextWNew = minWidth;
  $that.width(thatWNew);
  $next.width(nextWNew);

}).on("mouseup", function() {

  isDrag = false;
  // Convert widths to percent (to keep responsiveness)
  var contW = $cont.width();
  $box.css("width", function(i, w){
    return (parseInt(w,10) / contW * 100) +"%";
  });

});
```

```css
*{margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;}html,body{height:100%;font:14px/1.4 sans-serif;}

.box {
  width: 33.333%;
  float: left;
  background: #eee;
  position: relative;
}
.box:last-child .resizeHandler {
  display:none;
}
.boxContent{
  padding: 16px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.resizeHandler {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:2;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 6px;
  right: -6px;
  background: blue;
  cursor: e-resize;
} .resizeHandler:hover {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="boxes">
  
  <div class="box">
    <div class="boxContent">
      Adipisicing elit. Distinctio numquam accusantium perspiciatis quis ipsam modi optio odio quaerat magni! Repellendus, maxime voluptatum et sunt nobis, quae consequatur minus? Ducimus, voluptate!
    </div>
    <div class="resizeHandler"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="box">
    <div class="boxContent">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    </div>
    <div class="resizeHandler"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="box">
    <div class="boxContent">
      Sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores porro, ut aliquam, laudantium esse pariatur nihil provident vero quam excepturi. Incidunt fugit sit nihil, exercitationem sequi obcaecati, error impedit aspernatur!
    </div>
    <div class="resizeHandler"></div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

As you can see I moved the handlers **inside** each box.
On handler drag/move I target / modify the width of the handler's **parent box** and the width of the **next sibling box**. That's pretty much it. The code should be pretty self-explanatory, but as always, if you have questions feel free to ask.

---

#### Adding `.box` and `.row` dynamically:

Here's an example with dynamic BOX and ROW creation: ***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/lurawu/11/edit?html,css,js,output)***

```js
var minWidth = 50, // Set here the minimal resize width
    $box = $(".box"),
    $cont = $box.parent(),

    startX = 0,
    isDrag = false,

    $that, thatW = 0,
    $next, nextW = 0;




// GRIDDER ////////////////
var $selectedBox = null,
    $selectedRow = null,
    b = 0;

function newBox() {
  return $("<div/>", {
    class: "box",
    css: {width:"100%"},
    html : "<div class='boxContent' contenteditable>BOX "+ (b++) +"</div>"+
    "<div class='resizeHandler'></div>"
  });
}

$(document).on("click", ".box", function(){

  $selectedBox = $(this);
  $selectedRow = $selectedBox.closest(".row");

}).on("click", "#addRow", function() {

  if(!$selectedBox) return alert("Select a box first");
  $("<div/>", {
    class: "row",
    append: newBox(),
    insertAfter: $selectedRow
  });

}).on("click", "#addBox", function() {

  if(!$selectedBox) return alert("Select a box first");
  var $newBox = newBox();
  $selectedBox.after($newBox);

  var $rowBoxes = $selectedRow.find(".box"),
      totBoxes = $rowBoxes.length;

  $rowBoxes.css("width", function(i, w){
    return (100/totBoxes) +"%";
  });

});



// RESIZER ////////////////

$(document).on('mousemove', ".row", function( e ) {

  if(!isDrag) return;
  var x = e.pageX;

  var nextWNew = Math.max(minWidth, nextW + startX - x);
  var thatWNew = Math.max(minWidth, thatW + x - startX);
  if(thatWNew <= 50) return thatWNew = minWidth;
  if(nextWNew <= 50) return nextWNew = minWidth;
  $that.width(thatWNew);
  $next.width(nextWNew);

}).on('mousedown', ".resizeHandler", function( e ) {

  isDrag = true;
  startX = e.pageX;

  $that = $(this).closest(".box");
  thatW = $that.width();

  $next = $that.next(".box");
  nextW = $next.width();

  $box.css({userSelect: isDrag?'none':'auto'});

}).on("mouseup", function() {

  isDrag = false;
  // Convert widths to percent (to keep responsiveness)
  var contW = $cont.width();
  $box.css("width", function(i, w){
    return (parseInt(w,10) / contW * 100) +"%";
  });

})
```

```css
*{margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;}html,body{height:100%;font:14px/1.4 sans-serif;}

.row{
  clear:both;
  margin:10px 0;
  overflow:auto;
}
.box {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  background: #eee;
  position: relative;
}
.box:last-child .resizeHandler {
  display:none;
}
.boxContent{
  padding: 16px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.resizeHandler {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:2;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 6px;
  right: -6px;
  background: #448;
  cursor: e-resize;
} .resizeHandler:hover {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="addRow">ADD ROW AFTER</button>
    <button id="addBox">ADD BOX AFTER</button>

    <div id="page">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="box">
          <div class="boxContent" contenteditable>
            Adipisicing elit. Distinctio numquam accusantium perspiciatis quis ipsam modi optio odio quaerat magni! Repellendus, maxime voluptatum et sunt nobis, quae consequatur minus? Ducimus, voluptate!
          </div>
          <div class="resizeHandler"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
          <div class="boxContent" contenteditable>
            Sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores porro, ut aliquam, laudantium esse pariatur nihil provident vero quam excepturi. Incidunt fugit sit nihil, exercitationem sequi obcaecati, error impedit aspernatur!
          </div>
          <div class="resizeHandler"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
          <div class="boxContent" contenteditable>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
          </div>
          <div class="resizeHandler"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
          <div class="boxContent" contenteditable>
            Ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus non officia illum odit, optio inventore ad vero eos sed voluptas recusandae vel quod natus magnam totam quos, repellat mollitia veniam!
          </div>
          <div class="resizeHandler"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: How could make this dynamic ?, I worked hard to do it in 3 columns but want something dynamic that is a function wants the boxes add_row_column(3 or 2 or 1 or 4) fit the number of columns. example. http://i.imgur.com/X4eUN60.jpg I can add each row through jquery.append but I want you to help me with a function within that div container have the number of columns per row needs, please

Comment: @iLen yep, for dynamically appending `.box` inside every `.boxes` you should tweak a bit the above code. I'll show you how

Comment: If please you help me a lot if you add columns 1 function dynamically, I hope your code, thanks

Comment: @iLen something like this? http://jsbin.com/lurawu/11/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: staying well, you're very good. I would like to work like this in the picture, I think very quick and easy c'mon as it is your code, you could help me it looks like the image? http://i.imgur.com/80ImJG2.png

pd: I're helping a lot, I d.o.n.a.te in some mail?

Comment: @iLen Should not be hard to achieve what you want with the provided code.

Comment: You will do that change much faster than me, please help. One question, which is the variable that has the value of the width of each box?